# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.http.HttpStatus org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode()'

Tags: jakarta-migration, spring-boot-3

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.http.HttpStatus org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode()'

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.http.HttpStatus org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode()'
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.http.OAuth2ErrorHandler.hasError(OAuth2ErrorHandler.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:904)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:864)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:764)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:646)

No candidates found for method call response.getStatusCode().series()

I have upgraded springboot to 3.1.3 and the application is running fine, but when I do a http call, it fails with the above error, I'm including the dependencies in my build.gradle file

```
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
        classpath "org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.7.2"
    }

plugins {
    id 'idea'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.3'
    id 'checkstyle'
    id 'org.ajoberstar.grgit' version '1.7.2'
}

apply plugin: org.ajoberstar.gradle.git.base.GrgitPlugin
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'org.apache.logging.log4j') {
                details.useVersion '2.17.1'
            } else if (details.requested.group == 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core') {
                details.useVersion '2.14.1'
            } else if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.code.gson') {
                details.useVersion '2.10.1'
            } else if (details.requested.name == 'snakeyaml') {
                details.useVersion '1.33'
            }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:2.3.3'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:4.0.3'
    implementation 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.github.blagerweij:liquibase-sessionlock:1.6.0'
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1"
    implementation 'io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.97.Final'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:6.4.0'
    implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0"
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-common:2.2.0'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.2.7.Final'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:5.6.4'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc'

    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.12.261'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-beans'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0'
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:${springBootVersion}"){
        exclude group:'org.springframework.boot', module:'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}") {
        exclude module: 'xml-apis'
    }

    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}"

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.0-jre'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-context:2.2.5.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-ses', version: '1.11.128'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
    implementation group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:4.0.0'

    implementation group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth', name: 'spring-security-oauth2',   version: '2.5.2.RELEASE'

    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core'
    runtimeOnly "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.11"

    implementation 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.1.0'

    implementation group: 'com.jcraft', name: 'jsch', version: '0.1.54'
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.7'
    implementation group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version: '1.9.4'
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-datapipeline', version: '1.11.526'
    implementation 'org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core'
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-dynamodb', version: '1.11.373'

    implementation group: 'io.prometheus', name: 'simpleclient', version: '0.16.0'
    implementation group: 'io.prometheus', name: 'simpleclient_hotspot', version: '0.16.0'
    implementation group: 'io.prometheus', name: 'simpleclient_servlet', version: '0.16.0'
    implementation group: 'io.prometheus', name: 'simpleclient_spring_web', version: '0.16.0'
    implementation group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '4.4'

    implementation group: 'org.apache.pdfbox', name: 'pdfbox', version: '1.8.16'
    implementation group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.9.20'

    implementation group: 'com.stripe', name: 'stripe-java', version: '22.7.0'

    implementation group: 'com.nimbusds', name: 'nimbus-jose-jwt', version: '9.15.2'

    runtimeOnly 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.18.0'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'){
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic'
    testImplementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.10.0'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
    testRuntimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2:2.1.214'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc'
    testImplementation group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '2.0.7'
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-runner', version: '1.6.2'
    }
```

I've migrated from javax to jakarta, I couldn't figure out which dependencies are missing.
can you help me out?
If any information needed other than this, I can share those files as well! Thanks in advance:)

Comment: The way you are managing your dependencies indicates you are trying to outsmart Spring Boot. Some dependencies shouldn't be in there, some shouldn't have a version and some are just wrong and for older versions of SPring (Boot) and are incompatible. To start remove the version for the `spring-boot-starter-*` dependencies. Ditch the `hibernate-core` and `spring-beans` dependency and the `springh-security` ones are incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to outsmart the dependency management provided by Spring which hampers you in your upgrade strategy. You are trying too many versions and you are adding dependencies that you shouldn't be adding.

In short clean up/fix/improve your dependencies.

1. Remove the explicit versions from the starters.
2. Remove `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1`, Spring Boot 3.x requires Jakarta and this is already included by `spring-boot-starter-web`
3. Remove `javax.ws.rs-api` that is the wrong API and already comes with the implementation
4. Remove `jackson-databind`, as already included in `spring-boot-starter-web`
5. Remove `hibernate-core`, as already included in `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.
6. Remove the `spring-boot-starter-logging` exclude and `logback-core` and dependency, as excluding and then including again doesn't really make sense.
7. Remove version from `org.springframework.security` dependencies (already managed in proper and compatible version by `spring-boot-starter-security).
8. Remove `spring-beans` and `spring-webmvc` dependency (already available otherwise)
9. Remove `org.apache.tomcat.embed` dependencies, already available
10. Use `spring-boot-starter-web-services` instead of `org.springframework.ws` dependencies
11. Remove exclude from `spring-boot-starter-test`, `mockito-core` and `junit-jupiter` dependencies, the exclude already includes those.
12. Replace `spring-security-oauth2` with `spring-security-oauth2-jose` without a version.
13. Several other dependencies, h2, liquibase, prometheus are managed for compatible version by Spring Boot.
14. The `simpleclient_servlet` is for JavaEE and not JakartaEE, use `prometheus-metrics-exporter-servlet-jakarta` instead.
15. Metrics uses old libraries replace with the new Micrometer API instead.
16. Remove version from `spring-security-crypto`.
17. Replace `aspectj-weaver` with `spring-boot-starter-aop`.
18. Use the Spring Cloud AWS platform to manage the dependencies for AWS and Spring Cloud AWS

```
dependencies {
    classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
    classpath "org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.7.2"
}

plugins {
    id 'idea'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.3'
    id 'checkstyle'
    id 'org.ajoberstar.grgit' version '1.7.2'
}

apply plugin: org.ajoberstar.gradle.git.base.GrgitPlugin

dependencies {

implementation platform("io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-dependencies:3.0.0")
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:2.3.3'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:4.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson'
    implementation 'com.github.blagerweij:liquibase-sessionlock:1.6.0'
    implementation 'io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.97.Final'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:6.4.0'
    implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0"
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-common:2.2.0'

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.0-jre'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:4.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2'

    runtimeOnly "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.11"

    implementation 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.1.0'

    implementation group: 'com.jcraft', name: 'jsch', version: '0.1.54'
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.7'
    implementation group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version: '1.9.4'

    implementation 'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter'
    implementation 'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter-ses'
    implementation 'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter-dynamodb'

    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-datapipeline'


    implementation group: 'io.prometheus', name: 'prometheus-metrics-exporter-servlet-jakarta'     
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-core'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-observation' // Needed if you want spans/traces

    implementation group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '4.4'

    implementation group: 'org.apache.pdfbox', name: 'pdfbox', version: '1.8.16'

    implementation group: 'com.stripe', name: 'stripe-java', version: '22.7.0'

    runtimeOnly 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc'
    testImplementation group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '2.0.7'
}
```

Something like the above (cleaned up version) should do the trick. You probably endup with some compilation issues due to changed packages etc. I'm also not sure if `powermock-api-mockito2` will actually work with more recent supported versions of Mockito (or that you even need it).

You also might want to read the following migration guides:

1. [Amazon AWS](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/index.html#migration-from-2-x-to-3-x)

**NOTE:** Currently there is no Spring Cloud AWS version compatible with Spring Boot 3.x! So it might not work.

Comment: I did all the changes which you suggested,  but
Cannot resolve symbol 'HttpServletRequest', 'HttpServletResponse','ServletException', 'service' in 'MetricsServlet'

import io.prometheus.client.exporter.MetricsServlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
  private MetricsServlet servlet = new MetricsServlet();
  public void metrics(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    servlet.service(request, response);
  }

Comment: Which means you are still using an incompatible prometheus client (which is still using javax and not jakarta). Also not sure why you would need it with Spring Boot and the actuator in the first place? Replace `simpleclient_servlet` with `simpleclient_servlet_jakarta` if you really need/want to use that.

Comment: If i didnt mention the version, its giving me this error:
Could not find org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:.
If I add version to it, its giving "No candidates found for method call response.getStatusCode().series()" in 
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.http.OAuth2ErrorHandler.hasError(OAuth2ErrorHandler.java

If I add oauth2-jose rest client is showing errors

Comment: As stated it will give compilation errors which you need to fix, due to changed packages and support (read the various upgrade guides, you did read them instead of just blindy upgrade versions did you)!.

Comment: I also said the replace it (as I did in the gradle file which also had different coordinates).

Comment: Regarding prometheus you should probably add the Micrometer metrics and only use the prometheus exporter.

Comment: I also missed the `spring-security-crypto` version that should be removed.

Comment: If i didnt include this implementation 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1'
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter

Comment: That's because you still have a dependency depending on the javax servlet API. You've got a very detailed (and in my opinion valid) answer, which obviously took quite some time to build. It would be inappropriate to spend less time and effort to understand and apply it, than it took to understand your problems and write this solution and comments.

Comment: I don't have dependency which depends on javax servlet API. I spent so much time trying to figure this out, I'm new to spring.

Comment: Yes you do (as pointed out) the prometheus stuff was for JavaEE (as mentioned in the answer).

Comment: Scanning again the `Spring Cloud AWS Context` dependency is also old and will pull in deprecated dependencies. You should use the starter from AWS itself now (the project has been migrated as can be read [here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-aws)) so you need to change the version and coordinates for that.

Comment: HttpStatusCode getStatusCode()
No candidates found for method call response.getStatusCode().series().
  Gradle: org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.5.2.RELEASE (spring-security-oauth2-2.5.2.RELEASE-sources.jar)

Comment: HttpStatus httpStatus = ((HttpStatusCodeException) e).getStatusCode()
In some files, it was this which was giving error, 
Required type:
HttpStatus
Provided:
HttpStatusCode  , so I changed it to 
HttpStatusCode httpStatus = ((HttpStatusCodeException) e).getStatusCode()

Is this causing an issue ?